# BIRT boxes format in BIRT report

Tags: java, javascript, html, birt

is there any way to have a word in a boxes format where each character comes in a box for report. I am using 3.7 version.

[h][e][l][l][0]

I am showing by square brackets. but it should be single field (square boxes) in the report.

Usually for account numbers in forms are reported like this.

Waiting for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a background image (containing the blank boxes) or you'd have to use a GGrid and place each character in a distinct cell. Using JS, it should be easy to extract the n-th character of the string in the n-th column.